# Initial there is a text box with add icon at right of text box, on click of add icon...a new text box to be added below

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

[image: 1]

Initial there is a text box with add icon at right of text box, on click of add icon...a new text box to  be added below and for previous text box, add icon to be change to delete icon

Initial there is a text box with add icon at right of text box, on click of add icon...a new text box to  be added below and for previous text box, add icon to be change to delete icon

Comment: Show some code If you already tried for this

Comment: <button id="btnaddmapping1" class="button-default button-m panel-heading-margin" type="button" ng-click="Mapp();">
            <i class="di-block icon-add icon20 mr-0 v-sub"></i>
          </button>



<div class="form-group mb-5" ng-repeat="mapping in addUrlMapping track by $index">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="textbox">
</div>
</div>


controller:
have called that function of ng-click and assigned properties to it

Comment: @developer_jam, your code is AngularJs (not Angular). What are you using?

Comment: @Eliseo, angularJS

Comment: @Eliseo

can u suggest in angularJS

Comment: @developer_jam, it's the same. in this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/D2XlPcXzf8UvmO9s) you have the code in angular js (I updated the answer adding the code to AngularJs). NOTE: I'm a bit "oxidate" in AngularJs

Comment: @Eliseo thanks for help
can u tell which part of code is making add button to delete

Comment: It's the .css. See that I use [last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) and [not(:last-child)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not). .css get the last-child of "group", then search inside an input and the fisrt button (>input+button) or the second button (>input+button+button) and display or not the button. Another way can be forget the .css and use `<button ng-if="$last" ng-click="add()">add</button><button ng-if="!$last" ng-click="remove($index)">delete</button>`

Comment: @Eliseo
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75145419/issue-with-pop-up
can u look into this

Answer (score 0):

**Update** *17 January*: I added the trackBy in template driven form, else the "focus" is loose when enter anything in the inputs

In general, when we have a "series of buttons" we use an array.

Imagine some like

```
<div class="group" *ngFor="let bt of buttons;let i=index">
  <input> <button>add</button><button>delete</button>
</div>
```

If you use a .css like

```
.group:not(:last-child)>input+button{
  display:none;
}
.group:last-child>input+button+button{
  display:none;
}
```

The last "group" show the button "add" and the others show the button "delete"

Well. I imagine you want to store the inputs. So we can use a template driven form (use ngModel) or reactive Forms (use a FormArray)

Using template driven form

```
<div class="group" *ngFor="let value of values; let i = index;trackBy:trackFunction ">
  <input [(ngModel)]="values[i]" />
  <button (click)="add()">add</button>
  <button (click)="remove(i)">delete</button>
</div>
```

Where we define

```
  values:string[]=["",""]
  add()
  {
    this.values.push("")
  }
  remove(index:number)
  {
    this.values.splice(index,1)
  }
  trackFunction(index:number,item:string){
    return index
  }
```

If we use a FormArray we iterate over formArray.controls

```
<div class="group" *ngFor="let control of formArray.controls; let i = index">
  <input [formControl]="getControl(i)" />
  <button (click)="addControl()">add</button>
  <button (click)="removeControl(i)">delete</button>
</div>
```

And we use

```
  formArray=new FormArray([new FormControl(""),new FormControl("")])

  getControl(index:number)
  {
    return this.formArray.at(index) as FormControl;
  }
  addControl()
  {
    this.formArray.push(new FormControl(""))
  }
  removeControl(index:number)
  {
    this.formArray.removeAt(index)
  }
```

You have the two approach in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hfrmde?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**Update^** in Angular js it's the same, some like

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.
  module('plunker').
  controller('ComponentController', ComponentController);

  ComponentController.$inject = ['$scope'];

  function ComponentController($scope)
  {
      $scope.values = ['','']
      $scope.add = function add() {
         $scope.values.push('');
      };
      $scope.remove = function remove(index) {
         $scope.values.splice(index,1)
      };
    }
})();
```

And

```
  <div ng-controller="ComponentController">
    <div class="group" ng-repeat="value in values track by $index">
            <input type="text" ng-model="values[$index]">
            <button ng-click="add()">add</button>
            <button ng-click="remove($index)">delete</button>
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: yes angularJS
i need this input text to also be repeated along with repective add and delete